# iPad crashes when showing photos or taking photo--nil source view

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller, uialertcontroller

The follow code crashes when run on an iPad with the error message:

> (<UIPopoverPresentationController: 0x1377a19e0>) should have a non-nil
>   sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs.'

However, in my code I have the following, and I checked with breakpoints and console prinouts to ensure sourceview and barbutton are not nil. What do I need to do to avoid this? The error only appears on an iPad. Here is the method that causes trouble:

```
- (void)showChooseImageOptions {
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
UIAlertAction *chooseAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Choose From Photos" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    [self showLibrary];


}];
UIAlertAction *takeAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Take Photo" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    [self showCamera];

}];
self.directionsTextView.text=@"";
[alertController addAction:chooseAction];
[alertController addAction:takeAction];
UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {



    if (self.imageView.image)   {
        self.directionsTextView.text=@"Tap the circle to change the image";
    } else{
        self.directionsTextView.text=@"Tap the blue circle to choose or take an image";


    }

}];


[alertController addAction:cancelAction];
alertController.view.tintColor=[ColorSuperclass returnApplicationMainColor];






    alertController.popoverPresentationController.barButtonItem = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem;


if ( [alertController respondsToSelector:@selector(popoverPresentationController)] ) {

    // at least iOS8

    alertController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;


}

[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And the method showCamera and showLibrary are nothing but:

```
-(void)showCamera   {
if (TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)    {
    //do nothing, the simulator cannot handle pressing the take photos...
} else{
    [self showImagePickerForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
}
}

- (void)showLibrary {
[self showImagePickerForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
}
```

and the show source type method:

```
- (void)showImagePickerForSourceType:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType {
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover; //this line is very important, because otherwise, the tab bar could go out of scope (a consequence of using modal segues and tab controllers!)
imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;
imagePickerController.delegate = self;
imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but you shouldn't even add the "Take Photo" button unless the device/simulator supports taking a photo. Same for the "Choose From Photo Library" button. Each should be wrapped in a proper `if` statement ensuring the action is supported.

Comment: sure, all apple devices support this. To be safe, you use the IS_IPHONE/IPAD_SIMULATOR boolean (I forget the exact name) and if that boolean, just return the method early

Comment: Perhaps this is what you mean?

Comment: No. Use the provided method `UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:`. Make no assumptions. Even if the device has a camera doesn't mean you can actually take a photo.

Comment: Ok, will do. Why do you think an iPad is giving me so much trouble? Thanks

Comment: When does the error happen? Presenting the alert controller or the image picker?

Comment: [self showImagePickerForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];

Comment: "<address> should have a non-nil sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs.'" is the error

Comment: 0x19a236c38 <+180>: brk    #0x1 is the assemlby line it hits, I don't speak assembly tho.

Comment: Update your question with the code for your `showImagePickerForSourceType:` method. Since that is where it crashes that is what you should have posted from the start.

Comment: ^updated my question

Comment: The line: imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover; was something I adjusted specifically to avoid a dissapearing tab bar problem, and it seems to work at great at preventing the tab bar from dissapearing.

Comment: everything is happy as a clam on my iPhone, but it throws that error on the iPAD, hold on a moment I'll set a breakpoint and get you the exact line that is crashing.

Comment: Crashes on presenting sourcetype in the sourcetype presenting method.

Comment: aka [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;  solves it!

Comment: I have no idea why, however.

Comment: Look at your code for presenting the image picker. Now read the error. You need to do what the error is telling you.